# Connecting Logitech KB Bluetooth issue

Tags: keyboard, bluetooth

Elemental v6.1
Blue Tooth keyboard
Logitech 920-004013

Device shows up in Bluetooth as available on first attempt, but presents a code number on the OS screen to verify. Clicking “Pair” does nothing. The Blue tooth session gets “hung” and takes multiple “esc” button entries to clear.
Subsequent attempts show as failed to connect.
Strange thing is the keyboard worked perfect on Zorin v16.

Answer (score 0):

Should have Googled more myself…

bluetoothcl

list to see devices

disable then enable to see which MACAddress is the offending device

remove the device by MAC address

scan for devices

trust the device

pair the device

Enter the key code it gives you from the device

Done